# Picturebox Grid For Loop

Tags: c#

I am making a grid 32x32 of picture boxes which are all 20 pixels in width and height. I am also setting a random colour to each of them which I have the colours stored in a string array with the Hex information on the colour. When I start the game everything works perfectly which is great :) But it is time consuming grrr.. How can I improve my methods or algorithm to retrieve a quicker result? This is my code below:

```
public int getRandColour()
{
    tryAgain:
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randInt = rnd.Next(0, 8);
        if (randInt == previousColour)
        {
            goto tryAgain;
        }
        return randInt;
}
public void makeGrid()
{
    loadBar.Maximum = setSize * setSize;
    for (int x = 0; x < setSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < setSize; y++)
        {
            grid[x, y] = new PictureBox();
            grid[x, y].Tag = (Object)x;
            grid[x, y].Name = y.ToString();
            grid[x, y].Width = 20;
            grid[x, y].Height = 20;
            grid[x, y].Location = new Point(x * 20 + 20, y * 20 + 20);
            grid[x, y].Visible = true;

            currentColour = getRandColour();
            grid[x, y].BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(colours[currentColour]);

            gridColour[x, y] = currentColour;
            previousColour = currentColour;

            grid[x, y].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            grid[x, y].BringToFront();
            grid[x, y].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.paintBoxes);
            this.Controls.Add(grid[x, y]);
            loadBar.Value++;
        }
    }
    loadBar.Visible = false;
}
```

Is there a certain algorithm I can implement in my getRandColour() function for this to run quicker and make sure the last int is not the same as the new int?

Comment: A quick speed up would be to not `new` the `Random` class each time. Keep an instance of it alive and just call `Next()` when needed. There is a chance you will keep getting the same number until *enough* time passes. Also perhaps `while` instead of a `goto` would be a little more efficient.

Comment: How would I put the while into effect? I haven't used one before :/ @TyCobb

Comment: `while((randInt = rnd.Next(0,8)) == previousColour) {  } return randInt;`